# Python to Node/JS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, request

I'm reading a documentation for api but it's example is in python.
Here's the code:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.sportradar.us")

conn.request("GET", "/mma-t1/schedule.xml?api_key={your_api_key}")

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

But I'm using node. I tried to convert above code to this:

```
import request from 'request';

const key = Meteor.settings.sportradar.mma_v1;
const conn = `api.sportradar.us/mma-t1/schedule.xml?api_key=${key}`;

request(conn, (err, res, body) => {
  console.log('error:', err);
  console.log('statusCode:', res && res.statusCode);
  console.log('body:', body);
});
```

but I'm getting an error: Invalid URI.

The response will be in XML if that matters.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node you usually need to append http or https to the uri.

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Comment: Yep! I was waiting out the 10min before I could accept your answer.